# magento2.3 setup:upgrade after magento upgrade Type Error occurred when creating object

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, setup-upgrade

I Upgraded magento 2.1.8 to 2.3.5 and when I run setup:upgrade get the following error...

[image: error-image]

How can I get more details about this? It seems that Magento_Amqp is not compatible? It becomes after upgrade magento core.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this command:

```
rm -rf generated
rm -rf var/*
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```